# Thread safety: Does incrementing values of a primitive wrapper okay?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that Primitive wrappers such Integer, Double, Float are immutable, at least that was what I read. The thing is if we increment their values, each of the incremented value will be unboxed to their primitive representation and then assign the result to a new reference.

Now that I want to synchronize the incremented value but pretty much confused, because if I synchronize the initial values (before they get incremented) but I've no control over the new references unless I assign each of the new incremented values to new variables, means I have to always synchronize the new references every time I do increment.

How to deal with such situation?

Comment: You can write a method with synchronized to do the operations on your variable(s). Or as below use the concurrent package which introduced after JDK 1.5 which was written for your purpose.

Comment: Please show some example code of your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Atomic* (AtomicInteger, AtomicBoolean), where the synchronization part is inbuilt.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of worrying about all of that, why not check out [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) and [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)? All operations on them are atomic and they are threadsafe.

```
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

public int incrementCounter() {
    counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

From the documentation:

> An AtomicInteger is used in applications such as atomically incremented counters, and cannot be used as a replacement for an Integer.

Comment: is it okay using '+' operator for the AtomicInteger instead of using some inbuilts adding function?

Comment: No, Java has no support for redefining the operators to support that. You'd have to use one of the inbuilts, but for that you get thread safety and atomicity without having to worry about the implementation. Even if you could override + and - (like Scala or Kotlin), it would just end up calling these methods anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Use AtomicInteger or AtomicLong etc. It's all thread safe.**

Example :

```
AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(0);
integer.incrementAndGet();
integer.getAndIncrement();
```